# Re: c++ does anyone know what happened to Stroustrup's website

Tags: header-files

It looks like graphics libraries have removed... or the website needs overhaul.
In the absence of the header files developed by him, it is impossible to follow his book (PPPC++).

Thank you in advance for your help.

I was trying to compile Stroustrup's sample triangle program that uses
Simple_window.h and Graph.h header files.  Graph.h, in turn includes, GU.h header which I cannot find.